# flutter failed to build for releases not debug for Android

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

Dear all flutter experts,

Past two days i had headache for getting this message :

```
 * Where:
 Script '/Users/marendra/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle'  line: 1159

 * What went wrong:
 Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.
 > Process 'command '/Users/marendra/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

search the internet not found the answer.

Already tried flutter pub cache clean and flutter pub get  again, nothing worked.

Funny things, build for IOS succesfully trough XCODE not trough command line

My flutter doctor -v

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.4, on macOS 12.6 21G115 darwin-arm, locale en-ID)
• Flutter version 3.3.4 on channel stable at /Users/marendra/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision eb6d86ee27 (13 days ago), 2022-10-04 22:31:45 -0700
• Engine revision c08d7d5efc
• Dart version 2.18.2
• DevTools version 2.15.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
• Android SDK at /Users/marendra/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.0
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.0.1)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Build 14A400
• CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.72.2)
• VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
• Flutter extension version 3.50.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
• sdk gphone64 arm64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-arm64  • Android 13 (API 33) (emulator)
• macOS (desktop)             • macos         • darwin-arm64   • macOS 12.6 21G115 darwin-arm
• Chrome (web)                • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 106.0.5249.119

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
• All required HTTP hosts are available

Please help

Many thannks

Comment: can you show full error? There should be more error.

Comment: @umuieme there is no error, using verbose didnt show anything, then i just tried delete the flutter and install again the flutter

Answer (score 0):

To all guys that has the same problem with me, just reinstall the flutter...